# Appending to csv file in spark java creating new file always

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to append the new dataset to the file which is already there.
Following code i wrote:

```
ds3.coalesce(1).write().mode("append").option("header","true").option("compression","none").csv(Directory+"OUTPUT.csv");
```

But everytime it is creating a new file in OUTPUT.csv folder.
But my requirement is always it will append to the csv file rather than creating a new one.Someone have any idea and any better way to do as coalesce is very expensive in terms of performance.